# Partition function in renormalization

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, partition-function

When studying statistical mechanics, renormalization is understood from attempts to calculate partition function by simplifying. (For example, David Tong's [lecture note](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html))

While I understand that partition function allows one to calculate important thermodynamic quantities, what I do not get is why renormalization is understood as keeping partition function intact. Renormalization changes other quantities, such as temperature, free energy, so why should partition function be alone in being intact?

Edit/second question: also, texts confuse me on how renormalization is supposed to preserve partition function. Does it like map it exactly as $Z(K) = Z'(K')$ where $K'$ is a set of renormalized variables and $Z$ is partition function? Or is it more like $Z(K) = f(K')Z'(K')$? Texts seem to suggest both, and I am confused about that.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of renormalization is that you are changing all of these parameters in the precise way that keeps the partition function intact. In a sense, you're trying to find all the solutions to the equation $Z(K_0)=Z'(K')$, where $Z(K_0)$ is whatever bare couplings you start with. Sometimes, when doing this, authors will drop terms that correspond to multiplying the overall partition function by a constant, since these terms don't affect the physics, but this is purely cosmetic and you should *not* think of this as a fundamental part of renormalization.